# How to remove negative values from a created HAND model

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics, hydrology-toolset, hand

I have used ArcGIS to create a HAND (height above nearest drainage) using an SRTM DEM.

However, some small portions have negative values in the model which is supposed to have zeros as the minimum value.

Can anyone help me sort this problem out?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I think you are more likely to attract a potential answerer from amongst our volunteers if you provide the precise steps that you used to create your HAND model.